# drake: let the drake visualizer camera track a fast moving object

Tags: drake

I have a UAV flying pretty fast and I want to have the drake visualizer camera always track the UAV throughout the simulation time so that I can record a good video about it. I have followed "View->Camera Control Panel->Select Target->Track Mode" and tried different tracking modes, but none of them actually tracked the object when the simulation starts.

Am I using the right way to track the object, or do I need to write something else in code to make this tracking work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the feature does work as advertised.  I just tested with drake_visualizer, by clicking on the target and using smooth follow.  The only pain point is that every time you start a new simulation, the objects are recreated... so you have to click on the target again.  If you're trying to make your video, you might add an artificial pause at the beginning (e.g. StepTo(0.01), then wait, then call StepTo(end)) in order to give yourself a chance to click on the target, and start the recording.

I've opened https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/8765 to track it.